# How to design an interface to call functions with a parameter of varying type polymorphically?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

Say we want to be able to call functions `run` of `ImplementationA` and `ImplementationB` polymorphically (dynamically at runtime) through a yet to design interface in this example:

```cpp
struct Input {};

struct MoreInputA {};
struct ImplementationA {
    void run(Input input, MoreInputA more_input);
};

struct MoreInputB {};
struct ImplementationB {
    void run(Input input, MoreInputB more_input);
};
```

Both take some `Input` in the same format, but some `MoreInput` in different formats. `ImplementationA` and `ImplementationB` can only do their job on their specific `MoreInputA` and `MoreInputB` respectively, i.e. those input formats are fixed. But say `MoreInputA/B` can be converted from a general `MoreInput`. Then a simple polymorphic version could look like this:

```cpp
struct Input {};
struct MoreInput {};

struct ImplementationBase {
    virtual void run(Input input, MoreInput more_input) = 0;
};


struct MoreInputA {};
MoreInputA convertToA(MoreInput);

struct ImplementationA : public ImplementationBase {
    void run(Input input, MoreInputA more_input);
    void run(Input input, MoreInput more_input) override {
        run(input, convertToA(more_input));
    }
};

// same for B
```

However, now the `more_input` has to be converted in every call to `run`. A lot of unnecessary conversions are forced on a user of the polymorphic interface if they want to call `run` repeatedly with varying `input` but always the same `more_input`. To avoid this, one could store the converted `MoreInput` inside of the objects:

```cpp
struct Input {};
struct MoreInput {};

struct ImplementationBase {
    virtual void setMoreInput(MoreInput) = 0;
    virtual void run(Input input) = 0;
};


struct MoreInputA {};
MoreInputA convertToA(MoreInput);

struct ImplementationA : public ImplementationBase {
    void run(Input input, MoreInputA more_input);

    MoreInputA more_input_a;
    void setMoreInput(MoreInput more_input) override {
        more_input_a = convertToA(more_input);
    }

    void run(Input input) override {
        run(input, more_input_a);
    }
};

// same for B
```

Now it is possible to do the conversion only when the user actually has new `MoreInput`. But on the other hand, the interface is arguably more difficult to use now. `MoreInput` is not a simple input parameter of the function anymore, but has become some sort of hidden state of the objects, which the user has to be aware of.

Is there a better solution that allows avoiding conversion when possible but also keeps the interface simple?

Comment: what do you actually mean when you say "be able to call functions run of ImplementationA and ImplementationB polymorphically" ? When the user needs to know whether to provide either `MoreInputA` or `MoreInputB` then it isnt polymorphic. How would the calling code look like?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number An example for some calling code for the first suggested option could be `Input input = /*...*/; MoreInput more_input = /*...*/; ImplementationBase& impl = /*...*/; impl.run(input, more_input);` where `impl` could be a reference to an object of type `ImplementationA` or `ImplementationB`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am aware that there is nothing to be called polymorphically in the first code snippet. I edited the first sentence to try to clarify that. The question is indeed how to best add a polymorphic interface on top of the example in the first snippet. Two possible options for that are given in the 2nd and 3rd snippet.

Comment: Since you want to hide the complexity from your interface and differentiate through polymorphism, i think that this is a nice candidate for the bridge design pattern

Comment: If you want to call method exist only at `A`, then cast it to `A`, why not?

Comment: and imo it make no sense that `MoreInput` can be **converted** to `MoreInputA` **and** `MoreInputB` without any additional information while they're 3 different class...